# Firefox sync keeps asking for my password everytime it starts in any device

Tags: passwords, firefox-sync

I'm running Firefox in 4 different machines and they are all in sync mode. The problem is, everytime I start Firefox on any of these machines, I receive an alert saying that my account name or password are incorrect and that Sync will try again automatically. Nothing happens, so i click the preferences button beside the message, update my password and Sync starts to work fine. How can I solve this? I've deleted my account 3 times and started new ones but I'm still having the same issue. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What version of FF are you using? Latest? Googling for this issue turned up several ticket for it on various sites. https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+sync+keeps+prompting+for+password&oq=firefox+sync+keeps+prompting+for+password&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.10926&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Version 17.0.1 and I've also looked for a solution in google but could not find any. I'm begining to think that maybe my Router's default Firewall is blocking something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firefox 20.0.1. I solved it when I saw that my Sync password saved in Firefox (<kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Security</kbd> -> <kbd>Saved passwords</kbd> -> <kbd>Show passwords</kbd>) was not the same as the one I entered when I set up Sync. Some special characters (like `é`) were replaced by other characters.

So I solved the issue by changing my password and using only `a-z A-Z 0-9` characters.

(I filed a bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866586))